# Clean way to wrap-up and handle RMySQL connections?

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm fairly new to R, so forgive me if this is a amateur question. I still don't get parts of how the R language works and I haven't used closures enough to really build intuition on how to approach this problem.

I want to wrap up opening and closing a database connection in my R project in a clean way. I have a variety of scripts set aside that all use a common DB connection configuration file (I don't put it in my repo, it's a local file only), all of which need to connect to the same MySQL database.

The end goal is to do something like :

```
query <- db_open()
out <- query("select * from example limit 10")
db_close()
```

This is what I wrote so far (all my scripts load these functions from another .R file) :

```
db_open <- function() {
  db_close()  
  db_conn <<- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = db_user, password = db_pass, host = db_host)

  query <- function(...) { dbGetQuery(db_conn, ...) }

  return(query)
}

db_close <- function() {
  result <- tryCatch({
    dbDisconnect(db_conn)
  }, warning = function(w) {
    # ignore
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(FALSE)
  })

  return(result)
}
```

I'm probably thinking of this in an OOP way when I shouldn't be, but sticking db_conn in the global environment feels unnecessary or even wrong.

Is this a reasonable way to accomplish what I want? Is there a better way that I'm missing here?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is now done automatically in the dev version of RMySQL

Answer (score 2):

You basically had it, you just need to move the query function into its own function.  Regarding keeping db_conn, there really is no reason not to have it in the global environment.

```
db_open <- function() {
  db_close()  
  db_conn <<- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='Use14Characters!', dbname='msdb_complex', host='localhost')
}

db_close <- function() {
    result <- tryCatch({
    dbDisconnect(db_conn)
  }, warning = function(w) {
    # ignore
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(FALSE)
  })

  return(return)
}

query <- function(x,num=-1)
{
  q <- dbSendQuery(db_conn, x)
  s <- fetch(q, num);
}
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
query <- db_open()
results <- query("SELECT * FROM msenrollmentlog", 10)
db_close()
```